# See if a String has keywords provided in LinkedList with equals()

Tags: java, string, linked-list, equals, search-keywords

Given this situation, i want to see if the string contains ALL of the given keywords, atleast once/word.
My for loop does not seem to do it, so i'm interested if there is another way to try to solve the problem.

```
LinkedList<String> keyWords = new LinkedList<String>();
keyWords.add("amet");
keyWords.add("eiusmod");

String toCheck = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

String[] toCheckWords = toCheck.split(" ");

for (int i=0; i<toCheckWords.length(); i++) {
  if (keyWords.get(i).equals(toCheckWords[i])
     return true;
}
return false;
```

Expected to return true

Comment: You might want to use equalsIgnoreCase().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After splitting `toCheck` sentence into words store them in `Set` since your goal is to check if sentence contains keywords

- regardless of order,
- regardless of amount of repetitions (as long as it exists even once).

Since Sets are optimized towards *contains* method (for HashSet `contains` is close to O(1) time complexity) it looks like valid choice for this scenario.

Also `Set` provides [`Set#containsAll​(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) method and since `LinkedList` is a `Collection` we can use it like

So your code can look like:

```
LinkedList<String> keyWords = new LinkedList<String>();
keyWords.add("amet");
keyWords.add("eiusmod");

String sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
Set<String> wordsInSentence = new HashSet<>(List.of(sentence.trim().split("[ ,.!?]+")));

boolean result = wordsInSentence.containsAll(keyWords);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do this:

```
public static boolean check(String input, List<String> keywords) {
    for (String keyword : keywords)
        if (!input.contains(keyword))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Which you would call like this in your case:

```
check(toCheck, keyWords);
```

Comment: This method returns true, if the keyword is only a substring of a word in the input, i need it to see if the whole word is present

Comment: So you mean it has to be surrounded by spaces?

Comment: Wait what? I thought this didn't answer your question?

Comment: @tukevaseppo did you try to mark two answers with ✓ as both ware usefull? If yes then that is impossible since ✓ is meant to mark one answer, so it will stay at answer which you marked with it last. (I am not asking you to change your decision, just informing you since that happens sometimes).

Comment: @Pshemo Ah, I see what they did. Yeah, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The user, Schred, provided a solution which solves the problem and is perfectly valid. It is worth pointing out this is a perfect opportunity to use Set, specifically HashSet, if you're not bound by LinkedList. This will not work if the words are not case sensative.

```java
Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("amet", "eiusmod"));

String toCheck = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

boolean contains = Stream.of(toCheck.split(" ")).allMatch(keywords::contains);
```

Comment: I like how you added that "is perfectly valid" part. ;D

Comment: Haha well it definitely is. It directly solves the users problem using the exact same objects defined in the question :p.

Comment: Thank you, but that one-liner is just so clean. :O

Comment: I am not sure if that is what OP wants. If I understand correctly it is `toCheck` which needs to contain all keywords like when `toCheck = "foo bar baz foo"` `keywords = ["foo", "bar"]` result should be true because all keywords are within `toCheck`. Your code will also return true if only one keyword is found.

Comment: @Jason - Use `allMatch` instead of `anyMatch`.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see that the user wanted all keywords to match, my apologies.